# Using a cookie to store and get an integer

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cookies

A user starts off with 0.00 and after every click of an image, they earn an additional +0.05.

So I have

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#image1").one("click",function(){
   //
}
```

How can I create a cookie that stores the 0.00 on first page load and then adds 0.05 after every click of the image? The page is required to be refreshed after each click so it needs to be stored, I suppose.

Comment: create cookie in ready function and read and increment in click function

Comment: how about `localstorage`?? It's way better than `cookie` in this scenario!! or you can use **[Cookie plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/)**

Answer (score 4):

You can use `localStorage`

```
localStorage.setItem('cookieName', 0);
```

You can retrieve it using

```
localStorage.getItem('cookieName');
```

In you case it would be

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#image1").on("click",function(){
    localStorage.setItem('cookieName', localStorage.getItem('cookieName') + x);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This: It uses `localStorage` if supported, otherwise uses cookies.

```
var objCookie = {
    set: function (name, value, days) {
        try {
            var expires = '';
            if (days) {
                var date = new Date();
                date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
                expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
            }
            document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    },
    get: function (name) {
        try {
            var nameEQ = name + '=',
                ca = document.cookie.split(';');
            for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
                var c = $.trim(ca[i]);
                if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
            }
            return null;
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    },
    remove: function (name) {
        try {
            objCookie.set(name, '', -1);
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    }
};

var objLocalStorage = {
    set: function (name, value) {
        try {
            localStorage.setItem(name, value);
        } catch (e) {
            // alert('Local Storage is not supported');
            objCookie.set(name, value);
            console.log(e);
        }
    },
    get: function (name) {
        try {
            return localStorage.getItem(name);
        } catch (e) {
            // alert('Local Storage is not supported');
            return objCookie.get(name);
        }
    },
    remove: function (name) {
        try {
            localStorage.removeItem(name);
        } catch (e) {
            // alert('Local Storage is not supported');
            objCookie.remove(name);
            console.log(e);
        }
    }
};

$(document).ready(function () {
    objCookie.set('myKey', '0.0');

    $("#image1").one("click", function () {
        objCookie.set(parseFloat(objCookie.get('myKey')) + 0.5);

        // Refresh:
        window.location.reload();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage), or [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage#sessionStorage) for that. The values set to sessionsStorage will only last until the user closes the tab or his browser, whereas the loclaStorage last until it gets deleted.
Note: the dom-storage is a html5 feature, therefore will not be support by IE < 8. See [here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=namevalue-storage) for the browser-support.

The dom-storage only let you store strings, so you have to parse the values in order to cope with mathematical operations.

```
if(!localStorage.getItem('value')){ //check if there already are values saved
    localStorage.setItem('value', '0.00');
}
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#image1").on("click",function(){
       var value = parseFloat(localStorage.getItem('value')); //parse the string saved to the storage.
       value += 0.05; // add your value 
       localStorage.setItem('value', value.toFixed(2)); //round the value to 2 decimals 
   });
});
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ghcy0vs9/1/)**

To delete an item from the localStorage manually, you can use:

```
localStorage.deleteItem('value');
```

If you want to use cookies instead you can use:

```
document.cookie="theme=theme-dark"; //setter
```

and

```
var value = document.cookie; //getter
```

To print the points to your page you can use s.th. like the following:

```
var value = localStorage.getItem('value');
var par = $('<p />');
par.text('You have earned ' + value + ' points');
$('selector').after(par); //or .append() or s.th. similar what fits your needs
```

**[Demo 2](https://jsfiddle.net/79s0cn6c/)**

Comment: Thank you - how do I print the value of the item on the page?

Comment: @frosty you can simply use `localStorage.getItem('value')` to get the stored value, how do you want to print the value to the page ?