# jquery set option text when page is refreshed

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to change the text of dropbox when user select the text and want to set after the page is refreshed in wordpress template page.

> 
    Ireland

```
<option value="http://dignitytech.com/efront/united-kingdom-2/">United Kingdom</option>

<option value="http://dignitytech.com/efront/spain/">Spain</option>

<option value="http://dignitytech.com/efront/romania/">Romania</option>
```

Comment: Save the selected option in a cookie.

Comment: You can use **cookies** or **localStorage** to set the option selectable on page refresh.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29817432/2025923 For storing and retrieving the  data from `localstorage` when supported otherwise `cookies`.

Comment: Can you provide a short example, it is not clear to me, as I understand it those suggestions above are good but answers to a different question. E.g. 1. User choses option, 2. link is opened, 3. actually the same site is displayed with the option preselected (reason: bookmarking)

Comment: Hi When i click any option than the link to that option is to be open and the selected option is to be set in dropdown after the link is open.

Comment: Do you have the same dropdown on all those links that are in the dropdown?